# Ordering/moving option tag of a dropdown menu by city district and route

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Hi i have problem with drop down menu. I already remove duplicates now i want to put the route and district under the city. Since the dropdown is dynamic i use php from the database for filling it and i was thiking to use js for moving the option tag. This is my dropdown ask me if u need else :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXEMO.png)

[image]

```
enter code here
`<select class="select form-control filter-advertisement-show"
                        id="annuncio_id" name="annuncio_id" onchange="searchFilter2()" style="float: right; box-shadow: none;">
                    <option selected disabled hidden >{{__("Filtro per annunci")}}</option>
                    <option value="all"> {{ __('Tutti gli annunci') }} </option>
                    @foreach ($advertisements_with_packages as $advertisement)
                        @php
                            $district = $advertisement->address->district;
                            $locality = $advertisement->address->locality;
                        @endphp
                        <option style= "font-weight: bold;" data-order="1" id="citta" class="level_0 d-flex"value="@php $locality = str_replace(' ', '', $locality); echo $locality @endphp">@php echo $advertisement->address->locality @endphp</option>
                        <option style="margin-left: 20px; font-weight: bold;" data-order="2"  id="{{$advertisement->id}}" class="level_1" value="@php $district = str_replace(' ', '', $district); echo $district @endphp" data-id="@php $locality = str_replace(' ', '', $locality); echo $locality @endphp">@php echo  $advertisement->address->district @endphp</option>
                        <option style="margin-left: 20px;" data-order="3" id="route" class="level_2" value="{{$advertisement->id}}">{{$advertisement->address->route}}  {{$advertisement->address->street_number}}</option>
                        <script> 
                   /* (".selecet .option").each(function() {
                        $(this).siblings('[value="' + this.value + '"]').remove();
                    });*/
                    var optionValues =[];
                    $('#annuncio_id option').each(function(){
                        if($.inArray(this.value, optionValues) >-1){
                            $(this).remove()
                        }else{
                            optionValues.push(this.value)
                        }});
                </script>
                    <script>
                    let container =  document.getElementById("{{$advertisement->id}}");
                    let distretto = document.getElementById("{{$advertisement->id}}");
                    let strada = document.getElementById("route").value;
                    let option = document.createElement("option");
                        if(distretto === strada)
                            option.text = "fdgsfdgfdsgfds";
                            option.value = "sss"
                        container.add(option);
                    </script>`
```

Comment: Sort, order and get data from related controller. You can get data as JSON and append it to the your blade page using JS.

Comment: Yes, but how i can order like that

Answer (score 0):

This is an example. Please adjust this code according to your current situation. Js values mentioned in my example are not accurate and of course you know better your variables better than me. And you can add @php @foreach inside append (option) as you added in your question if necessary.

**View:**

```
<select class="select form-control filter-advertisement-show"
   id="annuncio_id" name="annuncio_id" style="float: right; box-shadow: none;">        
</select>
```

*JS in view:*

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#annuncio_id").on('change', function(){
         var annuncio = this.value;
            
            $("#annuncio_id").html('');
            
            $.ajax({
                    url: "{{url('/api/annuncio')}}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        annuncio_id: annuncio,
                        _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',                 
                    success: function (result) {                        
                        $.each(result.annuncio, function (key, value) {                                                         
                      $("#annuncio").append('<option style= "font-weight: bold;" data-order="1" id="citta" class="level_0 d-flex" value="' + value.address + '">' + value.address + '</option> <option style="margin-left: 20px; font-weight: bold;" data-order="2"  id="' + value.id + '" class="level_1" value="' + value.district + '">' + value.district + '</option> <option style="margin-left: 20px;" data-order="3" id="route" class="level_2" value="' + value.route + '">' + value.route + '</option>');
                    });                                           
                     }
                 });
              });  
           });      
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getAnnuncio(Request $request) {
  if($request->has('annuncio_id')) {
  $data['annuncio'] = AnnuncioModel::where('id', $request->annuncio_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

return response()->json($data);
 }
}
```

**Route:**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AnnuncioController;
Route::post('api/annuncio', [AnnuncioController::class, 'getAnnuncio']);
```

Comment: Hii i'm gonna try now, thaks for ur help

Comment: Hi the problem with this is the repetition. Print for every annouce the city district and rout e. If there is more announce under milan  i want it under it

Comment: Hi, my example works but shows under city only one route?

Comment: kinda work (i don't uderstand  this part AnnuncioModel::where('id', $request->annuncio_i). Right now print every city district and route for every advertise

Comment: I add an image in the post soo i explain better

Comment: Annuncio model, i meant the model(or DB table) from where you get data for showing it through controller to your view. What's the problem now? Describe please maybe i or other guys could help.

Comment: If u see in the image i post, i want to group by the city and district. Because rn only print city district for every advertise